# Upload JSON file or textarea input

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to have a form that includes both a textarea as well as a file upload field where I can either:
a) copy and paste JSON data into the text area, or
b) upload the same data as a text file

Upon submission, I want the PHP script to process the data (regardless of which one, textarea or file upload, never both.) I can get the textarea version to work just fine, but adding the file upload doesn't work. The script accepts the upload (I can dump $_FILES and get the data), but when I try to process the uploaded data (from a file input field), I get NULL as a result.

```
<?php
  if ((!empty($_POST['json'])) || (!empty($_FILES['file']))) {
    echo "<pre>\n";
    // The following DOES work when uncommented
    // var_dump(json_decode($_POST['json']));

    // This shows me the correct details, file name, tmp name
    print_r($_FILES);

    // This does not work. All I get is NULL
    var_dump(json_decode(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'])));
    exit;

  } else {

    echo <<<_END

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
     <head>
      <title>JSON Test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
      <div style="text-align: center;">
       <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <textarea rows="10" cols="80" name="json"></textarea><br /><br />
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit">
       </form>
      </div>
     </body>
    </html>
_END;

  }
?>
```

I'm pretty sure it's staring right at me, I just can't seem to figure out why it fails.

**UPDATE:** When I paste the JSON string in the textarea, I can parse it with no errors and get the data out. As I pointed out, this works. But if the same string is saved in a file and uploaded, that is what fails. In comparing the data, when I check for the string length when it's pasted in, I get 2154 bytes. But when it's uploaded as a text file, I get 2157 bytes. So there are extraneous characters there, somewhere.

This is a var_dump of the $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']:

```
Array
(
    [file] => Array
        (
            [name] => 20180208023303.json
            [type] => application/json
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php32oEwb
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 2157
        )

)
```

And when I look at the length of the same string paste in, strlen($_POST['json']) returns 2154.

Comment: What do you get if you do `var_dump(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));`? Do you get the contents of the file at all? Can you post the dump from that file?

Comment: The json_decode function returns null when the json is not valid (which, IMO, is pretty sad, because null can also be the result of valid json)
Instead, use json_last_error() or json_last_error_msg() to see what exactly went wrong.

Comment: in your condition !empty($_FILES['file']) is always set when you submit your form, you should check at least its size is > 0 when submitting form. You are also applying json_parse function when just "json" textarea is filled, which will you gave null. You should debug your function concatenation by checking file_get_contents is returning you a string and not false (error case); then checking if json_decode is returning you an object or null. After calling json_decode you can check if json contains errors by checking if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) as they already told you

Comment: Magnus, when I dump that, I get a string with the contents of the file that was uploaded. It's the same string I would get if I pasted it into the textarea input and submitted it. The difference that I noticed is, when I upload a text file, the length of the string is 3 bytes larger than if I paste the same exact contents in the textarea.

Comment: I added an update to the post.

Comment: Ace_Gentile, yes I'm aware that in its current state, I'm checking on both $_POST[] as well as $_FILES[]. I am manually alternating between them right now by commenting out one or the other. This is how I discovered that one works but the other doesn't. I will be adding in those checks once I can get both to work independently. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Stratadox, the JSON is valid. When pasted in the textarea and submitted, I can parse it fine and get the info out properly. I also ran it through jsonlint and it passes validation. However, json_last_error_msg() returns 'unexpected character'.